# How to display different iframes in the same container or area on my screen

Tags: html, iframe

I have HTML code that contains 3 images. What I'm trying to do is that when an image is selected, to display on the same screen (not a popup window) some text and an iframe.
To add some context, each image represents a building, clicking on an image will show both its address (some text) and its map (google map iframe).
In order to display the addr and map on the same screen, side by side, I have tried using .. to do this.

I'm not sure if using  is the right method to do this. I also tried to use formfields but couldnt get those to work either.

I'm still a newbie to this java coding ... its so exciting to learn, but keeping me awake night after night :-(

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :-)

Here is my code:

```html
<div style="display:none;">  
    <div id="leftfield" style="width:250px;">  
       /* placeholder for address */  
    </div>  
    <div id="rightfield" style="width:500px;">  
       /* placeholder for iframe */  
    </div>  
</div>  


<script>  
function showaddr(i) {   /* populate leftfield */  
if (i==1) {  
    document.writeln("title A");  
    document.writeln("Address line 1"); document.writeln("address line 2");  

} else if (i==2) {  
    document.writeln("title A");  
    document.writeln("Address line 1"); document.writeln("address line 2");  
} else if (i==3) {  
    document.writeln("title A");  
    document.writeln("Address line 1"); document.writeln("address line 2");  
}  
}  
function showiframe(i) {    /* populate rightfield */  
if (i==1) {  
    document.write('<iframe src="..." </iframe>');  
} else if (i==2) {  
    document.write('<iframe src="..." </iframe>');  
} else if (i==3) {  
    document.write('<iframe src="..." </iframe>');  
}  
}  
</script>  


<img onclick="showaddr(1); showiframe(1)" src="pic1.jpg" />  
<img onclick="showaddr(2); showiframe(2)" src="pic2.jpg" />  
<img onclick="showaddr(3); showiframe(3)" src="pic3.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you use jQuery and just change the src attribute of the iframe.

I have created a jsfiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KenQ/h3w5t8mj/3/)

```
<div>
    <div class="leftContent">
        <span id="title">empty title</span>
        <span id="adress">empty adress</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rightContent">
        <iframe id="map"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<img onclick="show(1)" alt="pic1" src="pic1.jpg" />
<img onclick="show(2)" alt="pic2" src="pic2.jpg" />
<img onclick="show(3)" alt="pic3" src="pic3.jpg" />

function show(type){
    showAdress(type);
    showMap(type);
}

function showAdress(type){
    $('#title').text('title ' + type);
    $('#adress').text('adress ' + type);
}

function showMap(type){
    $('#map').attr('src', 'http://jsfiddle.net/KenQ/h3w5t8mj/1/');
}
```